# Mary, the mother of Jesus and sister of Aaron?

Tags: quran, history

I came across an interesting few verses of the Qur’an, where God refers to the mother of Jesus as the sister of Aaron and also the child of imran (I could be mistaken, please check this)

> Quran 19:28 O sister of Aaron, your father was not a man of evil, nor was your mother unchaste."
>
> Quran 3:35 [Mention, O Muhammad], when the wife of 'Imran said, "My Lord, indeed I have pledged to You what is in my womb, consecrated [for Your service], so accept this from me. Indeed, You are the Hearing, the Knowing."

However, from what I understand; Mary’s brother is not Aaron. But, Miriam- a contemporary of Moses was indeed the sister to Aaron and daughter of imran.

If so, then why is Mary the mother of Jesus referred to as the sister of Aaron and child of imran in the Qur’an?